# using awk within loop to replace field

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have written a script finding the hash value from a dictionary and outputting it in the form "word:md5sum" for each word. I then have a file of names which I would like to use to place each name followed by every hash value i.e.
tom:word1hash
tom:word2hash
.
.
bob:word1hash

and so on. Everything works fine but I can not figure out the substitution. Here is my script.

```
$#!/bin/bash
#/etc/dictionaries-common/words
cat words.txt | while read line; do echo -n "$line:" >> dbHashFile.txt  
echo "$line" | md5sum | sed 's/[ ]-//g' >> dbHashFile.txt; done
cat users.txt | while read name
do
cat dbHashFile.txt >> nameHash.txt;
awk '{$1="$name"}' nameHash.txt;
cat nameHash.txt >> dbHash.txt;
done
```

the line

```
    $awk '{$1="$name"}' nameHash.txt;
```

is where I attempt to do the substitution.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the entire contents of the last loop (both `cat`s and the `awk`) with:

```
awk -v name="$name" -F ':' '{ print name ":" $2 }' dbHashFile.txt >>dbHash.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. I wish I could +1 you. So you must redeclare variables when used in an awk expression?

Comment: Awk won't take variables from the environment, no. Of course you could also do `awk -F : { print "'"$name"'" ":" $2 }'` instead. (As for +1, I believe you can still _accept_ the answer by clicking the checkmark thingy, which you should do if it worked for you. =)